# Loading while scrolling on Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, scroll

EDITS: I have eliminated the variable var path that I had to indicated the URL to the controller and used the url itself, now the path error is gone but I get no data. Something in the communication of the files is not being passed on.

What I am trying to do is upon scrolling, have the page load data from the server. For that purpose I am using a separate jquery file, a view, the controller and the model.

JQUERY FILE. You will see it is pretty straightforward:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var pageLoaded = 1; //this basically says that we are on page 1 of the results

      $(window).scroll(function()
       {

        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
         pageLoaded = pageLoaded+1; //when this condition has met, increase the pageLoaded so that I can tell php to load in data for page 2/3/4/5, etc, etc

/*// below I send the data to the controller named Home its function loadData gets a variable named id_load with value = to pageLoaded*/

         $.get('home/loadData', {'id_load':pageLoaded}, 
            function(data)
            {
                if (data != "")
                {
                 $('#submissions').append(data);
                }
             }
         );
         //alert(pageLoaded);
        }
       }
      );


    });
```

CONTROLLER:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');


class Home extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('load_model');
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

    }


    public function loadData ()
    {
        $pageNumber = $this->input->get('id_load'); 
        $this->load_model->loadPage($pageNumber);

    }


    public function index()  
    {
      $data = array('title' =>'homepage', 'main_content' =>'home_v');
      $this->load->view('template', $data); 

    }



}
```

and the MODEL should display the content as it gets new values while u scroll:

```
<?php


class Load_model extends CI_Model {



    public function loadPage ($pagenumber )

    {

        $sql = $this->db->where('id_load', $pagenumber)->get('data');

        $cadena = "";

        foreach($sql->result_array() as $reg)
        {
        $cadena =   $reg['content'];    

        }

        echo $cadena;


    }

}
```

Comment: if it is a .js file.. how will it be able to run php code `<?php  codes ?>`... think abt that ???

Comment: @bipen that's exactly what's happening :)

Comment: yes, I eliminated that in my edit. I tried to place the correct path but i am not getting it: it is localhost/html5ci/index.php/home/ on my URL box,

Comment: so you either have to get the base_url  as a javascript variable... or use this inside a php file

Comment: ok.. now... your path to the controller is incorrect i guess..

Comment: Firebug gives:

GET http://localhost/html5ci/index.php/home/html5/home/loadData?id_load=2
 
404 Not Found
  84ms 
jquery....min.js (line 2)

Comment: try my answer... i think that should work...that should atleast get the baseurl to your main.js

Comment: I got the correct path:

 $.get('/html5ci/index.php/home/loadData', {'id_load':pageLoaded},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

in your header `<head>` put a javascript varaiable with `base_url()` at the top..

here

**html**

```
<head>
  <script>
     var base_url=<?php echo base_url()?>;
  </script>
 ....
</head>
```

**jquery**

```
var path = base_url + 'index.php';
```

Comment: yes, bipen you are correct thank you, that is another right way to do the path. I also included it raw in the js file. Now the code works except one FUNNY thing:

Comment: The funny thing is that upon getting to my page, as there was not enough content, the scroller did not get activated. I have to have enough content to have a scroller present right on landing on my page. I suppose there are two ways, either get some loading of data on landing or use some javascript to tell "I want a scroller there" right from the start. What do you think ?

Comment: i think i would go for the first one.. get some loading of data on landing  :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you solved the problem. god bless you and long live Nepal :)

Comment: I gave you the correct answer, I marked it as such, I hope it added to your account

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem here is you didn't define or include the URL. the best practice to do this is, define or include base URL in the header section. put following line to the header

var base_url=;

so then use this base_url in anyware you want.